# Datasets representation in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, dataset

I have an array of two data sets that i want to represent in my component :

```
export default [
 [
   [1, 3],
   [2, 5],
   [3, 2],
   [4, 16],
   [18, 5]
 ],
 [
   [1, 16],
   [2, 23],
   [3, 5],
   [4, 3],
   [5, 1]
 ]
];
```

This is my component

```
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Graph data={this.props.datasets[0]} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I want to be able to represent both data sets in my graph:

```
data={this.props.datasets[0]} 
data={this.props.datasets[1]}
```

How can i pass both to the data of my graph component ?

Comment: Are you trying to merge the datasets into 1 array? Why not just send `this.props.datasets` as the `data` prop? It would help if you were a little clearer about what your expected output is and what shape the you want the data to take when passed into the `data` prop.

Comment: i can not in that way, i need to pass the 2 datasets

Comment: Can you just name the second prop something other than `data`?

Comment: I do not understandt exactly what you mean, try to put your answer with code example

Comment: basically i am following this tutorial https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/12/generating-svg-with-react/  and i am trying to display both data sets instead of selecting in the options

Comment: I want to help you, but I don't have time to read an entire tutorial. I'm also not sure what "...instead of selecting in the options" means. See my updated answer where you use `concat` to combine the two arrays into one array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is not a reserved property, like `style`. You can name your props differently if you want to pass them separately.

```
render() {
  return (

    <div>
      <Graph 
        dataOne={this.props.datasets[0]} 
        dataTwo={this.props.datasets[1]} 
      />
    </div>

  )
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can merge the data into a single array.

```
render() {
  return (

    <div>
      <Graph 
        data={this.props.datasets[0].concat(this.props.datasets[1])}
      />
    </div>

  )
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i can not because i need to use data, the component is mapped with this.props.data.map

Comment: if i use data twice it gets the last data set i pass in the graph, so i need to use only one data in the component